# I want to make splash screen using react native android

Tags: react-native

[image: Similar to this image]

I want to make splash screen using react native android similar to this image. how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this **react-native-splash-screen** library.

Follow the instruction for installation mentioned there. You can hide or show your splash screen using these methods.
Usage:

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'
export default class WelcomePage extends Component {    
        componentDidMount() {
            // do stuff while the splash screen is shown
            // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
            SplashScreen.hide();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, definitely you can use the react-native-splash-screen library.
Or you can also add them manually.
For detail, you can check out this link
https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate screen for splash screen and there you can check if user is logged in or not and navigate to specific screen based on the result

also you can reset the navigation stack like this

```
const loginAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
});

const homeAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],
});
```

the dispatch using

```
if (this.state.loggedIn)
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(homeAction);
            else
                this.props.navigation.dispatch(loginAction);
```